# Problem alignment issue with echo knowledge base

Tags: css, templates

Im currently using a plugin called echo knowledge base. But apparently i want to show it like this on the single post.

[image]
But apparently i only achieved this

[image]

To achieve on what i wanted, i need to create a singe-post.php (https://www.echoknowledgebase.com/documentation/customizing-current-theme-templates/) but i don't know where to start as the plugin keeps calling on a different functions on loading different files so i achieved the image on using display flex.

Here's what i have so far

```
css
#eckb-article-page-container #eckb-article-body #eckb-article-content #eckb-article-content-header{
display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}

#elay-sidebar-layout-page-container #eckb-article-page-container .eckb-breadcrumb{
order: 1;
}

#elay-sidebar-layout-page-container.elay-sidebar-template .elay-single-article .eckb-article-title{
order: 2;
}

#elay-sidebar-layout-page-container #eckb-article-page-container .eckb-navigation-back{
order: 3;
}

Html
<section class="elay-single-article eckb-article-defaults " style="width: 71%">

<div class="loading-spinner"></div>
<div id="eckb-article-page-container" class="">
    <div id="eckb-article-header"></div>
    <div id="eckb-article-body">
        <div id="eckb-article-left-sidebar"></div>
        <div id="eckb-article-content">
            <div id="eckb-article-content-header"><h1>Will construction members be available if needed?</h1>
                <div class="eckb-breadcrumb"
                     style="padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 4px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 0px; font-size: 12px;">
                    <div class="eckb-breadcrumb-label">You are here:</div>
                    <ul class="eckb-breadcrumb-nav">
                        <li><span class="eckb-breadcrumb-link"><a
                                href=""><span style="color: #000000;">Matador Metal Buildings</span></a><span
                                class="eckb-breadcrumb-link-icon ep_font_icon_right_arrow"></span>  </span></li>
                        <li><span class="eckb-breadcrumb-link"><a
                                href=""><span
                                style="color: #000000;">Construction</span></a><span
                                class="eckb-breadcrumb-link-icon ep_font_icon_right_arrow"></span>  </span></li>
                        <li><span class="eckb-breadcrumb-link"><span style="color: #000000;">Will construction members be available if needed?</span>   </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="eckb-navigation-back  "
                     style="margin-top: 4px; margin-right: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px; margin-left: 4px;">
                    <div class="eckb-navigation-button"
                         style="padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 4px; color: #666666; background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; border-radius: 3px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #dcdcdc;"
                         onclick="history.go(-1);">Back
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="eckb-article-content-body">
                <div id="kb-article-content">
                    <div class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid " style=" text-align:left;">
                        <div class=" full_section_inner clearfix">
                            <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
                                <div class="vc_column-inner ">
                                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                        <div class="vc_empty_space" style="height: 32px"><span
                                                class="vc_empty_space_inner">
        <span class="empty_space_image"></span>
    </span></div>


                                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                                <p>Although Matador Metal Building does not itself employ
                                                    construction crews to help you construct your steel building,
                                                    your dealer should be able to provide you with a list of
                                                    dependable contractors who can erect your building in a minimum
                                                    of time and at a reasonable cost.</p>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="eckb-article-content-footer"></div>
        </div><!-- /#eckb-article-content -->
        <div id="eckb-article-right-sidebar"></div>
    </div><!-- /#eckb-article-body -->
    <div id="eckb-article-footer"></div>
</div><!-- /#eckb-article-page-container -->
</section>
```

I can't achieve the alignment on what i want as the button and the paragraph content has a different column. I also tried using the two as a display content but wasn't achievable.

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so i fixed it by this.

```
jQuery( ".eckb-navigation-back" ).clone().appendTo( "#eckb-article-content-footer" );
```